# What is the SQL query to fetch the records prior to 90 days?

Tags: sql

i used the query as below where `DATE` is the Column.
But this is not working.

```
Select * from TABLE where DATE <= CURRENT_DATE -90 with ur;
```

Looking for suggestions.

Comment: "*not working*" is not a valid error message in any DBMS out there. The ANSI SQL way would be `where date <= current_date - interval '90' day`

Answer (score 0):

You could try DATEDIFF like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   MYTABLE
WHERE  ABS(DATEDIFF([DAY], DATE, GETDATE())) > 90
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your SQL engine. In MySQL you can do

```
Select * from your_table
where DATE <= curdate() - interval 90 day
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming google guessed right and you are using IBM DB2  this should be the syntax.

```
Select * from TABLE where DATE <= CURRENT_DATE -90 DAYS with ur;
```